# PHP Merge 3 array and iterate on basis of second key value ascending order

Tags: php, arrays

I've 3 array, now I want to merge them to form a new array and iterate them on the basis of key brand_name value in ascending order i.e I want to print Hp array first NOKIA second and samsung on last

First array

```
    $first=array(
id: "1",
model_no: "1520",
brand_name: "samsung",
description: "this is samsung",
price: "1200",
);
```

Second array

```
   $second=array(
id: "1",
model_no: "1100",
brand_name: "Hp",
description: "this is hp",
price: "1500",
);
```

Third array

```
    $third=array(
id: "1",
model_no: "1200",
brand_name: "NOKIA",
description: "this is nokia",
price: "1150",
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

$bigarray = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'model_no' => 1520,
        'brand_name' => "samsung",
        'description' => "this is samsung",
        'price' => 1200
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'model_no' => 1100,
        'brand_name' => "HP",
        'description' => "this is hp",
        'price' => 1500
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'model_no' => 1200,
        'brand_name' => "NOKIA",
        'description' => "this is nokia",
        'price' => 1150
    )
);


function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['brand_name'] > $b['brand_name'];
}

usort($bigarray, 'sortByOrder');

print_r($bigarray);

?>
```

This outputs:

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [model_no] => 1100
            [brand_name] => HP
            [description] => this is hp
            [price] => 1500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [model_no] => 1200
            [brand_name] => NOKIA
            [description] => this is nokia
            [price] => 1150 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [model_no] => 1520
            [brand_name] => samsung
            [description] => this is samsung
            [price] => 1200
        )

)
```

Now your array will be ordered as you desired.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this my code... i hope to help my code...

```
<?php $finalarray=array();
$first=array('id'=> "1",'model_no'=> "1520",'brand_name'=> "samsung",'description'=> "this is samsung",'price'=> "1200");


$second=array('id'=> "1",'model_no'=> "1100",'brand_name'=> "Hp",'description'=> "this is hp",'price'=> "1500");

$third=array('id'=> "1",'model_no'=> "1200",'brand_name'=> "NOKIA",'description'=> "this is nokia",'price'=> "1150",);

$finalarray =array_merge(array($first),array($second),array($third));

usort($finalarray, function($a, $b) {   return $a['brand_name']=="Hp"?-1:1; });

echo "<pre>"; print_r($finalarray);
```

output is

```
Array(    [0] => Array   (
        [id] => 1
        [model_no] => 1100
        [brand_name] => Hp
        [description] => this is hp
        [price] => 1500
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [model_no] => 1520
        [brand_name] => samsung
        [description] => this is samsung
        [price] => 1200
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [model_no] => 1200
        [brand_name] => NOKIA
        [description] => this is nokia
        [price] => 1150
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
<?php 
$arraycomplete = array(
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'model_no' => 1520,
    'brand_name' => "samsung",
    'description' => "this is samsung",
    'price' => 1200
),
array(
    'id' => 2,
    'model_no' => 1100,
    'brand_name' => "HP",
    'description' => "this is hp",
    'price' => 1500
),
array(
    'id' => 3,
    'model_no' => 1200,
    'brand_name' => "NOKIA",
    'description' => "this is nokia",
    'price' => 1150
)
);
for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($arraycomplete) ; $i++){
echo "ARRAY " . ($i + 1) . (".") . "<br>";
echo "id: " . $arraycomplete[$i]["id"] . "<br>";
echo "model_no: " . $arraycomplete[$i]["model_no"] . "<br>";
echo "brand_name: " . $arraycomplete[$i]["brand_name"] . "<br>";
echo "description: " . $arraycomplete[$i]["description"] . "<br>";
echo "price: " . $arraycomplete[$i]["price"] . "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```